# Receiving from Socket a string and separating into 3 ints by ","

Tags: python, string, sockets, split

I am using this code in RPi:

```
import serial, time, sys, threading, socket
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import serial
from pyfirmata import Arduino, util

### pyFirmata ###########################
# PINS: Digital outputs por PWM para simular um sinal analogico
#########################################
serialPort = '/dev/ttyAMA0' #use dmesg to check
BATTERY_LEVEL_PIN = 'a:5:i' #18?? 4 nao e analog
CAMERA_PIN = 'd:11:s'
LEFT_MOTOR_PIN = 'd:10:s'
RIGHT_MOTOR_PIN = 'd:5:s'
FLASH_LIGHT_PIN = 'd:2:o'
MOODLIGHT_RED_PIN = 'd:7:o'
MOODLIGHT_GREEN_PIN = 'd:8:o'
MOODLIGHT_BLUE_PIN = 'd:9:o'
PWM_MASTER_PIN = 'd:6:p'
MOTOR_MAX_VALUE = 170
MOTOR_MIN_VALUE = 8
CAMERA_MAX_VALUE = 135
CAMERA_MIN_VALUE = 30 
BATTERY_MIN = 0.5
BATTERY_MAX = 0.65
#########################################


#print 'setup done'
dim = False
step = 0.05
value = 0
cameraState = None
previousCameraState = None
cameraStateChanged = False
batteryCritical = False
behaviourRunning = False

board = None
moodPinR = None
moodPinG = None
moodPinB = None
pwmMaster = None
batteryPin = None
camPin = None
leftMotorPin = None
rightMotorPin = None
flashPin = None



def init(serial):
    print 'I WAS CALLED!!'
    global batteryPin, camPin, leftMotorPin, rightMotorPin, flashPin, moodPinR, moodPinG, moodPinB, pwmMaster, board
    board = Arduino(serial)
    it = util.Iterator(board, 0.05) #object board, interval
    it.start()
    time.sleep(0.01)
    batteryPin = board.get_pin(BATTERY_LEVEL_PIN)
    camPin = board.get_pin(CAMERA_PIN)
    leftMotorPin = board.get_pin(LEFT_MOTOR_PIN)
    rightMotorPin = board.get_pin(RIGHT_MOTOR_PIN)
    flashPin = board.get_pin(FLASH_LIGHT_PIN)
    moodPinR = board.get_pin(MOODLIGHT_RED_PIN)
    moodPinG = board.get_pin(MOODLIGHT_GREEN_PIN)
    moodPinB = board.get_pin(MOODLIGHT_BLUE_PIN)
    pwmMaster = board.get_pin(PWM_MASTER_PIN)
    # using iterator declared before, to prevent serial from overflowing
    batteryPin.enable_reporting()
    print 'JOB DONE!!'

# prints serial port information (not all settigs are displayed, only the ones modifiable by the user)
def printSerial(serial):
    print '------------------------------------------------------'
    print 'Opened port ' + serial.name+' with settings:'
    print 'Baudrate: ' + str(serial.getBaudrate())
    print 'Bytesize: ' + str(serial.getByteSize())
    print 'Read timeout: ' + str(serial.getTimeout())
    print 'XonXoff: ' + str(serial.getXonXoff())
    print 'Parity: ' + str(serial.getParity())
    print '------------------------------------------------------'


# custom funtion to clamp motor values
def clampMotor(value):
    return max(MOTOR_MIN_VALUE,min(value,MOTOR_MAX_VALUE))

# custom funtion to clamp camera values
def clampCamera(value):
    return max(CAMERA_MIN_VALUE,min(value,CAMERA_MAX_VALUE))


def writeValues(cam, mot1, mot2):
    camPin.write(clampCamera(cam))
    leftMotorPin.write(clampMotor(mot1))
    rightMotorPin.write(clampMotor(mot2))



init(serialPort)

# Sockets:

host = ''
porti = 1976
backlog = 5

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,porti))
s.listen(backlog)


# While port is open
while True:
#   ser.write("0")
    print "Waiting for a conection"
    client, address = s.accept()
    print "conected " + address[0] 
    while True:
        vals = client.recv(10)
        print "Received from socket " + vals
        if vals == '':
            break

        else:
                        val1, val2, val3 = vals.split(",")
                        val1 = int(val1)
                        val2 = int(val2)
                        val3 = int(val3)
            writeValues(val1,val2,val3)
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

With a proccessing program on the computer I am connecting to the socket and sending strings that are three numbers separated by comas: "90,90,90" for example.

> Waiting for a conection
>   conected 192.168.1.196 Received from socket 90,90,90
>
> 90,90,90
>
> Received from socket 90,90,90
>
> 90,90,90
>
> Received from socket 90,90,90
>
> 90,90,90
>
> Received from socket 90,90,90
>
> 90,90,90
>
> Received from socket 90,90,90
>
> 90,90,90
>
> Received from socket 90,90,90
>
> 90,90,90
>
> Received from socket 90,90,90
>
> 90,90,90
>
> Received from socket 90,90,90
>
> 90,90,90
>
> Received from socket 90,90,90
>
> 90,90,90
>
> Received from socket 90,125,125 
>   90,125,125
>   Received from socket
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "ClientForComputerFirmata2.py", line 126, in 
>       val1, val2, val3 = vals.split(",") ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

for some reason when I change the value of the numbers of the string, it says that it can be splitted as it only have one value, I don't have a clue why... could you help me please?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Is there a typo in your output or is 90,125,125 90,125,125 really the input you give it? If so, you're providing 4 numbers when you only expect 3. Thus your error.

Comment: No, is a mistake in the post that I dont know why happens. It is not spacing the last thing of the quote. I thing the problem is the last message is receiving is a " " but then it should break and not split it...

Comment: @javikomu: `recv(..)` might be returning only portions of your string. Print the value before splitting to see what is going on. Further, there is no guarantee that recv will give you the entire string at once. Remember, its just a long continuous stream of bytes of `recv(..)`. It might give you first portion in one call, and remainder in the next. The fix is to use a proper protocol through which you'll know when the first message has ended, and when the next message has started.

Comment: Does something like "45,45,45" work?  If so, you may need to increase the buffer size you pass to recv().  As Thrustmaster said, you may be getting a garbled portion for "90,125,125".

Comment: Ok. Now is not happening. I have a clue of what was happening. The last value of the string was a "\n". Can it be that?